# Cannot use a map method into a React component using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

I'm using React and TypeScript. Trying to map over an array containing objects - `shoppingItems` in this case.

```
type Props = {
  shoppingItems: [{
    id: (null | string),
    name: (null | string),
    isComplete: (null | boolean),
  }],
  toggleItem: any;
}

export const ShoppingList: Function = (
  {shoppingItems}: Props,
  {toggleItem}: Props,
) => {
  return shoppingItems.map((Item: any) => {
    return <Item Item={Item} key={Item.id} toggleItem={toggleItem} />;
  });
};
```

Here's App.js

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [shoppingItems, setShoppingItems] = useState<Item>([]);
  const itemNameRef = useRef<null | HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const toggleItem = (id: any) => {
    const newShoppingItem = [...shoppingItems];
    const Item = newShoppingItem.find((Item) => Item.id === id);
    Item.isCompleted = !Item.isCompleted;
    setShoppingItems(newShoppingItem);
  };

  const handleAddItem = (e: any) => {
    if (itemNameRef.current) {
    const itemNameCurrent = itemNameRef.current
    const name: (null | string | HTMLInputElement) = itemNameCurrent.value;
    setShoppingItems((prevItems: any) => {
      return [...prevItems, { id: uuidv4(), name: name, isCompleted: false }];
    });
    itemNameRef.current.value = '';
  }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ShoppingList shoppingItems={shoppingItems} toggleItem={toggleItem} />
      <div>
        <input ref={itemNameRef} type="text"></input>
        <br />
        <button onClick={handleAddItem}>Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

All I'm getting after clicking the button is: `React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

The aim is to display selected values of objects that are inside the array.

I also have `Item` component that is responsible for selection of values, but returns no errors so far.

How do I make the `shoppingItems` component expect object and also read `.map` as a method?

I tried to assign types to props inside the function. Then to Functional Component (instead of Props), but it was kind of hectic and I dealt with syntax errors every time. I wish I could pass an array of objects to `shoppingList` somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Your .map element is named `Item: any`. When you `return <Item` Item is not a component, but rather a `shoppingItem` object. Objects are not valid elements, and so you are seeing the `invalid type` error.

```
  return shoppingItems.map((Item: any) => {
    return <Item Item={Item} key={Item.id} toggleItem={toggleItem} />;
  });
```

You mentioned, that you have an `Item` component, so I imagine this is just a name conflict.

Try renaming `Item: any` to a different name.

```
  return shoppingItems.map((element: any) => {
    return <Item Item={element} key={element.id} toggleItem={toggleItem} />;
  });
```